# how to access Salesforce Attachment Body (base64 binary data) in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, salesforce, nt-native-api

I am working on iOS native app for getting attachments from salesforce.

I have to show the salesforce attachments in my iPhone app for particular object like Leads,Contacts etc. For that i am using `Rest Api` and got response body. But in response body there is url but i want binary data of attachment body.

Here is my code:

My rest api request

```
NSString *attachments=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select Name,Body, ContentType from   Attachment"];
SFRestRequest *request = [[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] requestForQuery:attachments];
[[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] send:request delegate:self];
```

I get response in body in following format:

```
{
    Body = "/services/data/v23.0/sobjects/Attachment/00P90000004SRFlEAO/Body";
    ContentType = "application/video";
    Name = "Video.MOV";
    attributes =     {
       type = Attachment;
        url = "/services/data/v23.0/sobjects/Attachment/00P90000004SRFlEAO";
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a GET request to the URL returned in the Body field to fetch the actual binary content.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but please clarify what exactly I have to do,which parameters need to be pass with the URL request .Should I request this URL like-        Instance URL+attachment body url

Answer (score 2):

Using this code to download after get body url:

```
SFRestRequest* downloadRequest = [self requestForFileContents:@"/services/data/v23.0/sobjects/Attachment/00P90000004SRFlEAO/Body"];

- (SFRestRequest *) requestForFileContents:(NSString *) path {
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
SFRestRequest *request = [SFRestRequest requestWithMethod:SFRestMethodGET path:path queryParams:params];
request.parseResponse = NO;
return request;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Check this code:
id url = @"http://blogs.independent.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/google-zip.jpg";
[self getImageBase64:url];


-( NSString *) AFBase64EncodedStringFromString: (NSData*) data
{
NSUInteger length = [data length];
NSMutableData *mutableData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:((length + 2) / 3) * 4];

uint8_t *input = (uint8_t *)[data bytes];
uint8_t *output = (uint8_t *)[mutableData mutableBytes];

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < length; i += 3) {
    NSUInteger value = 0;
    for (NSUInteger j = i; j < (i + 3); j++) {
        value <<= 8;
        if (j < length) {
            value |= (0xFF & input[j]);
        }
    }

    static uint8_t const kAFBase64EncodingTable[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

    NSUInteger idx = (i / 3) * 4;
    output[idx + 0] = kAFBase64EncodingTable[(value >> 18) & 0x3F];
    output[idx + 1] = kAFBase64EncodingTable[(value >> 12) & 0x3F];
    output[idx + 2] = (i + 1) < length ? kAFBase64EncodingTable[(value >> 6) & 0x3F] : '=';
    output[idx + 3] = (i + 2) < length ? kAFBase64EncodingTable[(value >> 0) & 0x3F] : '=';
}

return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:mutableData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}



-(NSString *) getImageBase64:(NSString *) url
{

NSURLRequest *         imageUrlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

NSURLResponse * response=nil;
NSError * error =nil;
NSData * data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:imageUrlRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];

if(error == nil)
{
    return [self AFBase64EncodedStringFromString:data];
}

return nil;

}
```